# How to ensure that a user can pass initial values into the form via @Input of an Interface

Tags: angular

I wanted to ensure that a user would enter user input in a form via the interface provided.
I have @Input assigned to the Interface and an input form and I'm wondering how to fix that via the Input.

**data.interface.ts**

```ts
interface Contact {
 name: string;
 phone: number;
 email: string;
 country: string;
 }
```

**app.component.ts**

```ts
@Input() Save: Contact
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="DataForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">

        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="email" formControlName="name" autofocus>
        </div>

        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="email"  formControlName="email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="text" formControlName="phone">
        </div>

        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="text" formControlName="country">
        </div>
    <button type="submit"   >Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use getters and setters (just make sure `DataForm` is already initialized before `OnInit` (you should initialize it in the constructor):

```js
@Input()
get Save(): Contact {return this._contact;}
set Save(contact: Contact) {
  if(contact) {
    this.DataForm.reset({...contact});
  } else {
    this.DataForm.reset();
  }
  this._contact = contact;
}
private _contact: Contact;

DataForm: FormGroup;

...


constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.DataForm = this._fb.group({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    country: ''
  });
}
```

Comment: that's great  @jullianobrasil, but I wonder if I enter any value in the form it still runs up, do you have an idea why it is so.

Comment: What do you mean by 'runs up'? Are you referring to raising events, like `valueChanges`? If you're asking if anything changes on the form behavior... no, it's still a regular form.

Comment: so I was thinking if user input is made and it doesn't match with the interface should be some kind warning or console reset. @julianobrasil

Comment: No, it won't happen. Once the set method finishes, every possible change won't affect anything, but the form itself, without any warning (we're actually copying the input value to the form, the object will be stored in the `_contact` private attribute and won't be affected by changes made in the form out-of-the-box).

Comment: oh okay, that's clear now! you are great, you can be a good mentor btw. @julianobrasil

Comment: I'm not sure if I answered you right. If the user input contains a field different from name, email, phone and country, that field won't affect anything, nor change the initial value of any form control. But it will be garbage in form value, internally (without any warning).

Comment: exactly, that was I wan thinking until your last comment before this you made it clear that it won't affect any changes. but initially that was i thinking.